# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, module

I keep trying to import sklearn but I when I do I get the error [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing']. I have upgraded numpy, pandas, scipy as well as scikit-learn to the latest versions but I still keep getting the same error. Any idea why. Here is the full error below:

```
'''

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>
----> 1 import sklearn

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     27 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     28 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 29 from .fixes import parse_version, threadpool_info
     30 from ._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr
     31 from .validation import (

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     17 import numpy as np
     18 import scipy
---> 19 import scipy.stats
     20 import threadpoolctl
     21 from .._config import config_context, get_config

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>
    465 from ._warnings_errors import (ConstantInputWarning, NearConstantInputWarning,
    466                                DegenerateDataWarning, FitError)
--> 467 from ._stats_py import *
    468 from ._variation import variation
    469 from .distributions import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_py.py in <module>
     35 from numpy import array, asarray, ma
     36 from numpy.lib import NumpyVersion
---> 37 from numpy.testing import suppress_warnings
     38 
     39 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing'

'''
```

Answer (score 2):

This cause due to the numpy version you are using. Therefore you  have to downgrade your numpy version to `1.16.4`. Use following command.

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.16.4
```

Reference :

https://github.com/DeepLabCut/Docker4DeepLabCut2.0/issues/26

Comment: I uninstalled the numpy version I had, however when trying to install numpy version 1.16.4 I keep getting an error on the terminal:

 ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

It seems pip is unable to install the stated version for some reason. Is there any solution for this

Comment: Can you try another lower version?As I understood there  are also a compatability issue with scipy and numpy.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, it turns out the problem was using a python version that was incompatible with the required version of numpy and scikit-learn. So I uninstalled the current version of python I was using which was python 3.8.5 on anaconda. Which basically meant uninstalling anaconda and installing the latest version of python 3.10.7 which doesn't have any compatibility issues between numpy and scikit-learn, and then manually re-installing the packages one by one. A pain, but at least it works...progress :)

Comment: And yeah you also have to re-install jupyter outside the anaconda environment, which takes a little getting used to but is highly rewarding when you get the hang of it as you won't be held back by any constraints from being tied to the conda environment.

Comment: I succumb to this, i had the same issue and all i had to do was to create a new environment variable and install the particular version of libraries i want to work with